# Could not initialize Eureka servlet context

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm upgrading my actual project to spring boot 2.5.2.
I had a config server, a zuul gateway and a discovery server.
Now I saw that spring cloud has an embedded gateway in my discovery server which I want to use. So I have at the end only the config server and discovery server (which includes my gateway)
But I get the following stack trace from the discovery server:

```
08-07-2021 14:03:46.449 [Thread-11] INFO  c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl.openForTraffic - Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
08-07-2021 14:03:46.449 [Thread-11] INFO  c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl.openForTraffic - Renew threshold is: 1
08-07-2021 14:03:46.449 [Thread-11] INFO  c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl.openForTraffic - Changing status to UP
08-07-2021 14:03:46.467 [Thread-11] ERROR o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServerBootstrap.contextInitialized - Cannot bootstrap eureka server :
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerBootstrap.contextInitialized(EurekaServerBootstrap.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration.lambda$start$0(EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration.java:68)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
08-07-2021 14:03:46.468 [Thread-11] ERROR o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration.lambda$start$0 - Could not initialize Eureka servlet context
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot bootstrap eureka server :
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerBootstrap.contextInitialized(EurekaServerBootstrap.java:77)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration.lambda$start$0(EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration.java:68)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerBootstrap.contextInitialized(EurekaServerBootstrap.java:73)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
```

Here is my code:

### Config server:

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.geminiald</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-service</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <name>config-service</name>
    <description>Configuration service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

#### application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/shared
  profiles:
    active: native
  security:
    user:
      password: configPassword

server:
  port: 8081
```

#### shared/discovery-service.yml

```
server:
  port: 8082

logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: DEBUG
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: TRACE
```

### Discovery server

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.geminiald</groupId>
    <artifactId>discovery-service</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <name>discovery-service</name>
    <description>Discovery service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

#### Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

#### GatewayDiscoveryConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayDiscoveryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator
            discoveryClientRouteLocator(ReactiveDiscoveryClient discoveryClient, DiscoveryLocatorProperties locatorProperties) {

        return new DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator(discoveryClient, locatorProperties);
    }
}
```

It would be very appreciated if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eureka server cannot run as webflux and therefor cannot be combined with spring cloud gateway. Did you mean for gateway to be a eureka client?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anybody at all.

The context was null hence NPE was fixed for me by adding tomcat-embed-core.jar into the classpath.